# How to connect specific pulseaudio clients

Tags: pulse-audio

I've got two applications running via `padsp`. How can I (hopefully at runtime) make sure the output from the first is recorded by the second?

Answer (score 1):

First, when you start the OSS-applications, give them and the streams names to make it easier to identify them:

```
padsp -n oss_play -m oss_output your/playback/app
padsp -n oss_rec  -m oss_input  your/recording/app
```

To pipe output from one app into the other, we'll use a null-sink and the associated monitor. Load it from the commandline:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=oss_pipe sink_properties=device.description=OSS-Pipe
```

Now you can either use `pavucontrol` to set the output of *oss_play* to *OSS-Pipe*, and the input of *oss_rec* to *Monitor of OSS-Pipe* using the GUI. Or you can again use the commandline to identify the index number of the streams with

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
pacmd list-source-outputs
```

The output isn't particulary parse-friendly, but if you want to use a script, [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrep.html) does the trick (for "oss_play", similarly for "oss_rec"):

```
sgrep '"index: "__"\n" in ("index" .. ("index" or end)  containing "application.name = \"oss_play\"")'
```

Say the indices are 3 and 17, respectively. Finally, move them:

```
pacmd move-sink-input 3 oss_pipe
pacmd move-sink-output 17 oss_pipe.monitor
```

If `module-stream-restore` is loaded (default), pulseaudio will remember the default sources/sinks for those applications as long as it is active, and connect them for you automatically when you start them again.

Comment: I know the answer is probably too late for the OP, but I ran into the same problem and wanted to document the solution.

Comment: very appreciated :)